# Need help understanding this line

Tags: java, math, binary, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

thank you in advance for this basic question.

I am going through a tutorial and I see this line.

```
int a = (n & 8) / 8
```

This is supposed to identify whether the fourth bit from the right is a binary representation of 0 or 1.  I understand the concept of bits etc, but I do not understand what mathematical equation (if any) this represents.

Would anyone care to explain how this would be written in a mathematical equation?  Also, please let me know if i am missing anything else in my understanding of this line.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to understand that `&` is "bitwise AND" and operates on the binary representation of the number.  Google "bitwise AND" and you should find some good materials.  Further, once the "8" bit has been isolated, dividing the result by 8 moves that bit down to the "1" position.  Work it through on paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The expression ( n & 8 ) 
   does Logical And of n with  1000 binary.
2. So that gets the 4th bit from right.
3. then dividing that by 8, shifts the value right 3 binary places.  I.e. it moves the 4th bit to the rightmost place.

That is more clearly expressed as  " >> 3"

So your overall expression would be something like:

```
  (n AND 1000 )  >> 3
```

And that leaves the 4th bit of N in a temporary variable, as bit 0 (rightmost bit).
All the other bits will be zero because of the AND.

Comment: Ditto ono the +1. Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 2):

`8` in decimal is `1000` in binary

so if you do [`bitwise AND`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)  with any number

```
n & 8
```

it will stay `8` only if the 4th bit is `1` and

if you divide it by 8 again it will return 1, zero otherwise

**For example**

for `9` (`1001`)

```
9 & 8
```

would be

```
  1001
& 1000
 ------
  1000
```

Now for the case where forth bit is `0`

for `7` (`0111`)

```
7 & 8
```

would be

```
  0111
& 1000
  -----
  0000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = (n & 8) / 8;
```

The `n & 8` applys a logical `AND` mask to the 4th bit of `n`;

```
     n: 11001010 // example value
     8: 00001000
result: 00001000
```

Dividing that number by 8 brings the result to the lowest bit :

```
result: 00000001
```

Dividing a number by `2^n` shifts the numbers `n` bits to the right (in the same way that multiplying by `2^n` shifts bits to the left).

The result is assigned to variable `a`, which now contains 0 or 1, depending on the value of the 4th bit.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operator works on bits and performs bit-by-bit operation. Assume if  `a = 60`; and `b = 13`; now in binary format they will be as follows:

```
a = 0011 1100
b = 0000 1101
a&b=0000 1100
```

then **a&b** is also an **integer** which is further divided by 8 in your example.